# SilverStripe - Using the CheckboxsetField with MultiForm Module

Tags: php, module, silverstripe

I have a form using the multiform module. I have a checkboxsetfield populated by a dataobject.

When saving the form I am getting strange results. For instance if I select the first and third checkboxes then this is how the array appears in the database: 1{comma}3 when I expected to see 1,3

MyDataObject.php

```
<?php
...
       if($SomeData = DataObject::get('SomeData')->sort('SortColumn'){
        $fields->push( new CheckboxSetField('SomeData', 'Field Name', $SomeData->map('ID', 'Name')
        ));
    }
```

MultiForm.php

```
<?php
...

public function finish($data, $form){

        if(isset($_SESSION['FormInfo']['MultiForm']['errors'])){
            unset($_SESSION['FormInfo']['Form']['errors']);
        }

        parent::finish($data, $form);

        $steps = DataObject::get('MultiFormStep', "SessionID = {$this->session->ID}");

        $MyStep = $this->getSavedStepByClass('MyStep');

        if($this->getSavedStepByClass('MyStep')){
            if($MyStep->loadData()){
                $MyDataObject = new MyDataObject();
                $MyStep->saveInto($MyDataObject);
                $MyDataObject->write();
            }
        }
...
```

Any ideas how to process the array?

Answer (score 1):

[`CheckboxSetField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-CheckboxSetField.html) does have code which refers to [`{comma}`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-CheckboxSetField.html#194-222) when saving to the DB or when calling the [`dataValue`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-CheckboxSetField.html#224-243) function. This is essentially escaping any commas that were defined as values in the string when saving to a single column.

This tells me that either your multiform isn't providing the right input to `CheckboxSetField` or that there is more to this situation than your code is showing.

If `CheckboxSetField` gets an array like `array('1,3')`, that is when I would expect to see that type of result. Calling `map` like you have returns an [`SS_Map`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_Map.html) object which may not automatically convert the way you are expecting. Try adding `->toArray()` after the `map` call when you are passing the values into the `CheckboxSetField`.

If that doesn't solve the issue, we probably will need to see the `DataObject` itself and a few other bits and pieces of information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Turnerj,

I've done as you have suggested but still the same results. I totally agree with what you say about the usual behaviour of checkboxsetfield, I have another on a different form which works totally fine. The problem is to do with MultiForm Module I think. I'll try and gather some more examples of code to show tonight.